# Why value of `X` in iife chage based on the way we access it?

Tags: javascript, iife

I have following js code.

```
var a = (function(){
    var x = 0;
    var y = function(){
        x++;
        console.log(x);
    }
    var z = function(){
        return x;
    }
    return {
        x, y, z
    }
})();
```

Here when I try to access `a.x` for the first time, It is giving me output `0`(which is expected as x is initialized to 0), Then I am incrementing the value of `x` using function `y`. But after incrementing value of `x` two times(or maybe more then 2), when I try to access the value of `x` it is stll giving me `a.x=0`. I am not able to understand why it is happening as I already change the value of `x` using function `y`. Then why it is not changing.

(But when I am accessing value of x through some function it is giving incremented value. Why this different behavior. if the same variable I am directly access then it will give some output and when the same variable value I am returning through some function it is giving some other value. Why?)

```js
var a = (function(){
  var x = 0;
  var y = function(){
 x++;
 console.log(x);
  }
  var z = function(){
 return x;
  }
  return {
 x, y, z
  }
})();

console.log(a.x);
a.y();
a.y();
console.log(a.x);
console.log(a.z());
```

I **guess** it is because of closure but not sure about it.

Comment: because a.x is only going to be the value what it was initially set with. It is not a reference to the variable.

Comment: but I am changing it's value using `y`, then it should change, but why not changing?

Comment: y is a function.... you are not changing a function, you are executing it. If variables changed after we referenced them, we would have a big issue in our applications.

Comment: Thanks, got the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an object and return it:

```
return {
  x, y, z
}
```

The `x` property in the object receives a *copy* of the local variable `x`. It is not bound in any way to the local variable other than that, so subsequent changes to the variable in the closure are not reflected in that object.

You could make a getter:

```
return {
  get x() { return x; },
  y, z
};
```

That will cause any access to the "x" property of the returned object fetch the current value of `x` in the closure.

Comment: Thanks, understood the reason.

Comment: I guess "a copy of the local variable"  is a bit confusing wording, because if `x` was an Object, that wouldn't be a copy in the strict sense. It would be more correct to say that `{x}` (and in general `y=x`) bounds to the (current) value of `x`, not to `x` itself.

Comment: @georg well even for an object, an assignment always copies the *real* value of the source; a reference to an object is a *reference* value, and though the object referenced can be internally modified, the reference won't be. If the closure assigned a new object to the local `x`, in other words, the `x` property in the returned object would still refer to the original object.

Comment: @Pointy: thanks for the explanation ;) just saying that "a copy of the variable" sounds confusing - you cannot really "copy" a variable (which is just a name).

Comment: Oh I don't disagree; the actual precise semantics of "values" in a language like JavaScript are complicated and subtle.

Answer (score 3):

The last line:

```
   return { x, y, z };
```

is the same as:

```
  return { x: x, y: y, z: z };
```

So it *copies* the local variables into the object. For functions or objects that doesn't matter as they are copied by reference, primitives however are copied by value, therefore you got two different `z`, a local variable and the object property.

Comment: Thanks, understood the reason.